# Libpoco: build failed if a sub directory in path contain pattern *.o*

Tags: makefile, poco-libraries

Poco building is failed if any of the sub directory contain `*.o *` pattern. For example if the build directory named `temp.ortfd`, so while building POCO it treats `temp.ortfd` as the object file not as sub directory and throws the following error:

> No rule to make target /home/abc/clone/temp.o needed by /home/abc/clone/temp.ortfd.../AbstractContainerNode.o [... means path of poco directory till that file]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution . Change the regular expression in makedepend.gcc file.

Instead of .o give the regular expression .o$